# Is it advisable to implement changing app language from settings in a native iOS app?

Tags: ios

Will my app be rejected from app approval in App store if it is implemented?

Comment: Why do you need to change the app language within the app itself?

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist, I am not sure. It's designed by the UI designers. Is it advisable to do?

Comment: In my opinion the best practice would be to respect the users preferred language on their device unless you have a strong reason not to. That way the user gets the same language as they would see in other apps and the rest of the system and you can rely on the system to pick the right localization for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No @Doj Yias, It is not necessary that you have to change our app-language according to device's setting app.

You can give the option of selecting language with-in your app like most of the e-commerce application does that. It will not get your app rejected.

**How to implement multi-linguality:**

You just need to `localized` to your project according to different languages and add the lingual strings to the respective lingual files.

**To choose language, you have to use:**

[image]

```
    if let mainP = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "en", ofType: "lproj"), let bundle = Bundle(path: mainP) {
        return NSLocalizedString(self, tableName: nil, bundle: bundle, value: "", comment: "")
    }
```

You have to pass language code at the place of `"en"`.

Comment: Ok @ankit, Can you help me understand how to implement fetching a new language from the backend for the application? It seems NSLocalizedString is not changeable!

Comment: thank you for the screenshot. What if I want to update the localisation file for Thai at runtime? How would I do that?